# How do I adjust cooking time for dense fruitcake in smaller pans

Tags: cooking-time

I'm making a fruit-laden very dense fruitcake.  The original recipe is for 2 standard loaf pans but I'm using 4 small loaf pans (all I know is external dimensions are 6.875 x 3.625 x 2.125)

Recipe says 3 to 3 1/2 hours (check for toothpick comes out clean after 3 hours) @ 275 degrees.

I assume a smaller cake will cook in less time but other than checking all the time with a toothpick, I have no idea how long they will take.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wow, that's a long baking time! I can't help much, but when I make mini-cupcakes instead of regular sized ones I start checking times at half the time and it usually takes a little longer than that. My recommendation would be to start checking at 1 1/2 hours.  Also, I'm assuming you're measuring in inches because those would be teeny in cm. OH!  one other thing, I believe I've heard that if you make the pan smaller, you may want to raise the baking temperature a tiny bit.

Comment: Also, you always want to measure baking pans by their INTERNAL dimensions.  That's what recipes use. It sounds like you have sort of an odd size that may actually be closer to a mini than a small. Adjusting time is based on volume, so if you're actually 1/4 the volume, you'll need 1/4 the time.

Comment: Yes those are inches and I copied them off the package.  Internal would make more sense though!  I ended up baking them for 2 hours and I think they're perfect - but it's a very, very dense fruit-laden cake - not sure that would apply to other recipes.

Comment: Did it all fit into the four small loaf pans?  The dimensions you gave seem like each small loaf pan would be equivalent to about 1/3 or at most 2/5 of the volume of one standard loaf pan.

Comment: Not 4 but it fit 3 perfectly.  I filled them 2/3 full and the bread rose just to the top.